# Rename a set of files with pattern <name>.1.gz.html to <name>.html

Tags: rename, mv

I tried to use the command:

> mv *.1.gz.html *.html

But, I got the response:

> `<filename`> is not a directory.

How can I get this working? I tried the rename command as well, but, I couldn't get that working either. Too much regex for me.

I think using xargs would work, if I understood that better.

Comment: Just using the shell: `for file in *.html; do mv "$file" "${file/1.gz./}"; done`... See [the Wooledge wiki on PE](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mv` either renames a single file or moves many files into a single directory.

If you want to rename many files you probably want to use `rename`.

Depending on your version of `rename` you do:

```
 rename .1.gz.html .html *.1.gz.html
```

or

```
 rename 's/\.1\.gz\.html/\.html/' *.1.gz.html
```

The first version is a bit easier to write the second one is more powerful and sometimes available as `perl-rename`. Have a look at `man rename` to find the correct syntax.

Comment: The 2nd rename worked. The first and simple one gave me an error. I have version 5.20.2 of rename installed.

Comment: This also worked for me: `rename 's/1\.gz\.//' *.1.gz.html`

Answer (score 1):

A wildcard like that gets expanded into everything that matches it *before* the `mv` command even runs.  Making matters worse is that `*.html` will also match your `*.1.gz.html` files.

This means that (for example two files named `abc.1.gz.html` and `def.1.gz.html`) your command above is essentially running:

`mv abc.1.gz.html def.1.gz.html abc.1.gz.html def.1.gz.html`

This will try and move `abc.1.gz.html` and `def.1.gz.html` into a directory called `def.1.gz.html`.  Thankfully this fails as that file is not a directory.

You'll need to script something to look at each file one at a time
eg:

```
for file in *.1.gz.html; do
  mv "$file" "`echo $file | sed 's/\.gz\.html$/.html/'`"
done
```